# Open Editor in an Eclipse PDE View programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am creating an eclipse plugin with a view, called DataView. I want the Java Hex Editor to open in my DataView that I created. I followed [this](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseEditors/article.html) vogella post, which stated that getViewSite().getPage(), would force the editor to open in the DataView. However, when I test the code, the DataView opens separately from the editor. Note: I am using Java 8 by company requirements.

**Is there anyway to fix this?** I have attached my code and my current output below:

```java
@Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    
        Text text = new Text(parent, SWT.WRAP | SWT.READ_ONLY | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
        Font font = new Font(text.getDisplay(), new FontData("Courier", 12 , SWT.NONE));
        text.setFont(font);
         
        File file = FileData.getDataFile();
        URI fileURI = file.toURI();
        
        //String workspacePath = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getLocation().toString();

        IFileStore fileStore = EFS.getLocalFileSystem().getStore(fileURI);
        if (!fileStore.fetchInfo().isDirectory() && fileStore.fetchInfo().exists()) {
            IWorkbenchPage page = getViewSite().getPage();
            try {
                IDE.openEditor(page, fileURI, "net.sourceforge.javahexeditor", true);
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link does not say that the editor will open in the view, it is just telling you how to open an editor from a view. Editors always open separately in the editor area.

You can't have an editor in a view. You can use the core editor classes such as `TextViewer` and `SourceViewer` in a view but that means you can't reuse code from an existing editor unless it is designed to allow this.